# how to set relative height of row in grid according to screen size in extjs sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I set the relative height of a grid according to screen size in ExtJS?

I am using two grids in single screen underneath each other. When the first grid is populated with data, the first grid should use up as much space as it needs and the second grid should expand over the rest of the screen.

How can we set a relative height to the second grid so that the first one can expand and collapse based on the data?

Answer (score 0):

In modern you can set the first grid to "infinite: false" (Ext.grid.Grid), while you add a "flex: 1" to the second.

In classic you would have to set the height of the first grid, as soon as you know the amound of rows (number of records) you received.